# iOS - Phonegap or WebApp keyboard issue

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm new in iOS programming, and I have a little problem with the keyboard...
That's a webapp, the application shows simply the mobile website.

In this website, there are forms, and in this forms, there are input type file fields. When the user clicks on input type text field, the keyboard appears, logical, isn't it ?

But **when the user clicks on input type files fields, the keyboard does some weirds things.** Sometimes it's not totally visible, sometimes it's misplaced, and the most of times, that's both... You can view it on this awesome screenshot I've made.

Is there anyone who can help me to fix this issue ?

---

[image: Awesome screenshot]

Comment: Is this entire view a single WebView, or do you have other Native UI Components showing up on here?

Comment: There is a webview (from Cordova/PhoneGap framework) which take the whole screen; and upper this webview, I've added a GADBannerView from AdMob library.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you are setting up the views?  I have experienced something similar to this, and I might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I just update Cordova, and the problem was fixed...

So, to all the people which have this problem, **simply update Cordova** ;-)